# How to find out whether my stash was already committed somewhere?

Tags: git

I tend to collect a lot of stashes. Right now I have 18 of them. Probably 17 are just stashes I committed in roughly that form, and didn't delete for whatever reason. But maybe one of them contains some important, uncommitted diffs that I can't remember, but that I wouldn't want to lose. But it is tedious to check for every stash whether I've committed these or similar changes somewhere, partly because I don't even know the branch anymore where I might have committed them, let alone the commit itself.

**For a given stash, how can I find out whether the changes contained in it already exist more or less in some commit, in some branch?**

What do I mean by "more or less"? Well, it's pretty clear what I'd mean if I'm asking for a commit being exactly equal to a given stash. But often one will modify something after applying the stash, so chances are that there is no commit matching my stash exactly. For the purpose of the question, I'm looking for the commit that contains *most line changes from the stash in question*.

Comment: A nice script is given here to identify if a stash is already applied or not :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962942/how-can-you-tell-if-a-git-stash-is-no-longer-required . One you identify already applied stash, you can delete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the changes in your stash against any branch to see what they'd add to that branch:

```
git diff master stash@{0}
```

will tell you what would be added/deleted to/from the master branch if you applied the most recent stash there.

So if it was partially applied, you'd only see the parts that are missing.